# Drag and Drop DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

How do you make a DataGrid in C# ASP.net so that you can drag and drop the rows to reorder them. I want to use the actual DataGrid tool from the toolbox not a lookalike.

Comment: I don't think the `DataGrid` control has that functionality out of the box.  You can probably use jQuery UI Draggable on the client-side to re-order rows in the view, but that wouldn't affect anything on the server-side in the actual data unless you send some sort of updates to a server-side handler (such as an AJAX call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HERE](http://aspsnippets.com/demos/321/) is demo !

As David said , you can use JQuery to drag and drop DataGrid' Rows !

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".drag_drop_grid").sortable({
        items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        connectWith: '.drag_drop_grid',
        axis: 'y',
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        receive: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
        }
    });
    $("[id*=gvDest] tr:not(tr:first-child)").remove();
});
```

And you can find a full reference [HERE](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Drag-and-Drop-GridView-Rows-with-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx) :)
Good Luck !